# A POST method API Express Node.JS not working, SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 68 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, post

I'm trying to make this post API work, its an API to post some data to a table in my database, but every time I tried it on postman it gives me this kind of error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 68
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (C:\javascript-projects\living-main\API\node_modules\express\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
    at C:\javascript-projects\living-main\API\node_modules\express\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:128:18
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
    at invokeCallback (C:\javascript-projects\living-main\API\node_modules\express\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:231:16)
    at done (C:\javascript-projects\living-main\API\node_modules\express\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:220:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\javascript-projects\living-main\API\node_modules\express\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:280:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

This is my function code for the insert query in the models folder:

```
const dbpool = require('../config/database')

const createNewRecruitment = () => {
  const SQLQuery = `INSERT INTO tb_recruitment_teams () 
                    VALUES (
                      '${body.identifier_recruitment_team}',
                      '${body.name_team}',
                      '${body.post_team}',
                      '${body.domicile_team}',
                      '${body.job_description}',
                      '${body.experience}',
                      '${body.certificate}'
                      )`;
  return dbpool.execute(SQLQuery);
}
module.exports = {
  createNewRecruitment,
}
```

My POST code in recruitment.controllers.js

```js
const ProjectModel = require('../models/tb_recruitment_team')

const createNewRecruitment = async (req, res) => {
    const {body} = req;
    try{
        await ProjectModel.createNewRecruitment(body);
        res.json({
            message: 'Create New Recruitment Success',
            data: body
        })
    }catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Server Error',
            ServerMessage: error,
        })
    }    
}

module.exports = {
   createNewRecruitment,
}
```

My routes in recruitment.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const RecruitmentControllers = require('../controllers/recruitment.controllers');

const router = express.Router();

//CREATE - POST
router.post('/', RecruitmentControllers.createNewRecruitment);

module.exports = router;
```

and my app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const recruitmentRoute = require('./routes/recruitmen.js');

const middlewareLogRequest = require('./middleware/log.js')

app.use(middlewareLogRequest);

app.use(express.json({ strict: false }))

app.use('/recuitments', recruitmentRoute);

module.exports = app;
```

and this is the body JSON that I use for testing my POST in Postman:

```json
{
            "identifier_recruitment_team": '34',
            "name_team": 'NTDD',
            "post_team": 'Balikpapan',
            "domicile_team": 'Job Description Contributor',
            "job_description": 'ERTBB',
            "experience": 'ERTBB',
            "certificate": 'ERTBB'
}
```

Did I do something wrong? I've been searching for it but I still didn't get it.

The POST method to save data work and will give the right `res.json`.

Comment: Typo?  JSON uses double-quotes, but some of your string values in the JSON shown are single-quotes.

Comment: @David omg yes, now it can work, but sadly its still not working like I intended it's return the error msg 
{
    "message": "Server Error",
    "ServerMessage": {}
} 
does my code still wrong?

Comment: That sounds like a separate problem, and one that merits further debugging.  The code shown appears to explicitly return a response like that if an exception is caught, so you'll want to debug and observe what that exception is and what operation is failing.

Comment: ok! I will work in it then. thankyou so much for your help for my silly mistake haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that your JSON body is invalid, JSON doesn't accept single quotes `' '`, use instead double quotes `" "` for your values

Try this:

```
{
            "identifier_recruitment_team": "34",
            "name_team": "NTDD",
            "post_team": "Balikpapan",
            "domicile_team": "Job Description Contributor",
            "job_description": "ERTBB",
            "experience": "ERTBB",
            "certificate": "ERTBB"
}
```